# On Ventura do I still open a .itl file after Option-clicking on the Music app?

Tags: itunes, external-disk, music, music.app

After a few steps:

1. Connect external drive to (old) macOS running Big Sur.
2. Format drive (APFS).
3. Still on macOS running Big Sur: `cp -pr ~/Music /Volumes/MyDisk/`
4. Connect external drive to (new) macOS running Ventura.
5. [Option-click on `Music` app](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/music/mus7663a920a/mac); select `/Volumes/MyDisk/Music/iTunes`

At this point I can load the file `iTunes Library.itl` and everything *seems* OK, but that file (`iTunes Library.itl`) is several years old, and the music collection, including "Last Played", reveals that I'm looking at old data.

**On Ventura do I still open a .itl file after Option-clicking on the Music app?**

**If a `.itl` file is not the right one to select; which one is?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, do not choose the `.itl` file. It is a leftover file from the `iTunes` app (the one with the CD icon).

The new `Music` app uses `~/Music/Music/Music Library.musiclibrary`
(rather than `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.itl`).

[image: Music App Choose Music Library]

Notice that by default `Finder` conceals the extension (of both files and, in this case, folders). Hence the folder appears as `Music Library`.

If you've been maintaining your library for many years, the actual music files will be inside the `~/Music/iTunes` folder.

(Future work: The two checkboxes `Keep Music Media folder organized` and `Copy files to Music Media folder when adding to library` are already checked. Find out how to move out of `~/Music/iTunes` and into `~/Music/Music` for good.)